# Java Frame - Game

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Getting an error at frame.add(game);:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Debug Current Instruction Pointer
    - The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments 
     (Display)

My code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Display game = new Display();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `Display` is not a component and can't be added to a `JFrame`

Answer (score 4):

Your class `Display` should *extend* a [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) (`Container, Button, Canvas, Label ...`). I think you would like to extend `JPanel` which is the most common, but it really depends on what `Display` class is intended to do:

```
public class Display extends JPanel {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Display` should `extend JPanel` or some other `Component` as mentioned by the other answer.

For your purpose you should also override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method when you are ready to draw something on the `Display`and have a constructor if your going to use it as a Component.

Comment: Huh?? The first paragraph is correct, but the second seems to have no relevance to the posted question

Comment: @peeskillet It seemed like OP wanted to make a game. Eventually, something needs to be drawn, right?

Comment: It's _possible_ but there was no reference to it. A game _could_ be made with no painting _at all_

Comment: @peeskillet The reference to the game intention is in the title and the way the variables are named. If OP didn't really need the information...I'm sorry :(

Comment: Yea whatever, who knows what the OP wants. +1 for the first part :)